# Why is my html displaying a snippet of js as body text?

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna preface this by saying I'm very new at this and learning as I go so there may be several mistakes in this and I'm open to all helpful feedback!

I created this bit of animated text forked from a codepen pen using a combo of html/css/js and it's running exactly as it should be, except a little while after the animated text finishes loading, it adds a portion of my nested js as visible html text. I think it has something to do with a rogue unclosed ">" somewhere because the portion of js that it's mistakenly displaying exists between two unrelated ">" and "<". Can anyone explain why this is happening? TIA! full code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
    <style type="text/css">

        .var-highlight{
          color: #07573e; font-style: italic;
        }
        .string-highlight{
          color: rgba(253, 149, 90, 0.8);
        }

        #typewriter{
            font-size: 0.7em;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: "Courier New";

            &:after{
              animation: blink 500ms linear infinite alternate;
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes blink{
          0%{opacity: 0;}
          100%{opacity: 1;}
        }

        @-moz-keyframes blink{
          0%{opacity: 0;}
          100%{opacity: 1;}
        }

        @keyframes blink{
          0%{opacity: 0;}
          100%{opacity: 1;}
        }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <pre id="typewriter">
    </span> hmmm
     seems I've gotten myself all turned around... 
     could've sworn the road was back that way...
     I guess uncertainty seems appropriate 
     for matters of this world
     only thing I can really be certain of these days 
     is that</span> <span class="var-highlight">I'm so-and-so and I exist</span>
     anyhow, looking back is a bad habit, y'know
     while we're both here,
     might as well take a look around...
     ...well? 
     you gonna do somethin'?
     or are you just gonna stand there and bleed?<span/><type>
</body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

            function setupTypewriter(t) {
        var HTML = t.innerHTML;

        t.innerHTML = "";

        var cursorPosition = 0,
            tag = "",
            writingTag = false,
            tagOpen = false,
            typeSpeed = 105,
          tempTypeSpeed = 0;
      
        var linePause = 1500;

        var type = function() {
          
            if (writingTag === true) {
                tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
            }

            if (HTML[cursorPosition] === "<") {
                tempTypeSpeed = 0;
                if (tagOpen) {
                    tagOpen = false;
                    writingTag = true;
                } else {
                    tag = "";
                    tagOpen = true;
                    writingTag = true;
                    tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
                }
            }
            if (!writingTag && tagOpen) {
                tag.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
            }
            if (!writingTag && !tagOpen) {
                if (HTML[cursorPosition] === " ") {
                    tempTypeSpeed = 0;
                }
                else if (HTML[cursorPosition] === "\n")
                  {
                    console.log("newline detected");
                    tempTypeSpeed = linePause;
                  }
                else {
                    tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 50;
                }
                t.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
            }
            if (writingTag === true && HTML[cursorPosition] === ">") {
                tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 50;
                writingTag = false;
                if (tagOpen) {
                    var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
                    t.appendChild(newSpan);
                    newSpan.innerHTML = tag;
                    tag = newSpan.firstChild;
                }
            }

            cursorPosition += 1;
            if (cursorPosition < HTML.length - 1) {
                setTimeout(type, tempTypeSpeed);
            }

        };
              return {
            type: type
        };
    }

    var typer = document.getElementById('typewriter');

    typewriter = setupTypewriter(typewriter);

    typewriter.type();
      </script>
</html>
```

Comment: `<script>` tags belong **inside** either `<head>` or `<body>`

Comment: `<type>` should probably be `</pre>` and some of your `</span>` should be `<span>`. No idea what that last `<span/>` is about. HTML works with opening (eg `<span>`) and closing (eg `</span>`) tags or self-closing tags (eg `<img />`). It should be well structured

Comment: You might want to start with this [Introduction to HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML)

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. This was my first (and probably only) experiment with anything programming-related so it’s been a bit confusing trying to keep track of all the new info. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few small errors here, most notably a missing `</pre>` tag (which is causing the script issue)

```
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <pre id="typewriter"> <--------- this opening tag is missing a closing tag
    </span> hmmm
     seems I've gotten myself all turned around... 
     could've sworn the road was back that way...
```

Comment: You might want to tackle _all_ the HTML structure problems in OP's code to make this answer more helpful

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
    <style type="text/css">

        .var-highlight{
          color: #07573e; font-style: italic;
        }
        .string-highlight{
          color: rgba(253, 149, 90, 0.8);
        }

        #typewriter{
            font-size: 0.7em;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: "Courier New";

            &:after{
              animation: blink 500ms linear infinite alternate;
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes blink{
          0%{opacity: 0;}
          100%{opacity: 1;}
        }

        @-moz-keyframes blink{
          0%{opacity: 0;}
          100%{opacity: 1;}
        }

        @keyframes blink{
          0%{opacity: 0;}
          100%{opacity: 1;}
        }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <pre id="typewriter">
    <span> hmmm
     seems I've gotten myself all turned around... 
     could've sworn the road was back that way...
     I guess uncertainty seems appropriate 
     for matters of this world
     only thing I can really be certain of these days 
     is that</span> <span class="var-highlight">I'm so-and-so and I exist</span>
     <span>
     anyhow, looking back is a bad habit, y'know
     while we're both here,
     might as well take a look around...
     ...well? 
     you gonna do somethin'?
     or are you just gonna stand there and bleed?</span></pre>
</body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

            function setupTypewriter(t) {
        var HTML = t.innerHTML;

        t.innerHTML = "";

        var cursorPosition = 0,
            tag = "",
            writingTag = false,
            tagOpen = false,
            typeSpeed = 105,
          tempTypeSpeed = 0;
      
        var linePause = 1500;

        var type = function() {
          
            if (writingTag === true) {
                tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
            }

            if (HTML[cursorPosition] === "<") {
                tempTypeSpeed = 0;
                if (tagOpen) {
                    tagOpen = false;
                    writingTag = true;
                } else {
                    tag = "";
                    tagOpen = true;
                    writingTag = true;
                    tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
                }
            }
            if (!writingTag && tagOpen) {
                tag.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
            }
            if (!writingTag && !tagOpen) {
                if (HTML[cursorPosition] === " ") {
                    tempTypeSpeed = 0;
                }
                else if (HTML[cursorPosition] === "\n")
                  {
                    console.log("newline detected");
                    tempTypeSpeed = linePause;
                  }
                else {
                    tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 0;
                }
                t.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
            }
            if (writingTag === true && HTML[cursorPosition] === ">") {
                tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 0;
                writingTag = false;
                if (tagOpen) {
                    var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
                    t.appendChild(newSpan);
                    newSpan.innerHTML = tag;
                    tag = newSpan.firstChild;
                }
            }

            cursorPosition += 1;
            if (cursorPosition < HTML.length - 1) {
                setTimeout(type, tempTypeSpeed);
            }

        };
              return {
            type: type
        };
    }

    var typer = document.getElementById('typewriter');

    typewriter = setupTypewriter(typewriter);

    typewriter.type();
      </script>
</html>
```